# Wordpress Parent->Child sidebar navigation

Tags: wordpress, navigation, sidebar

I'm looking to create a menu so that once you click into a section the section is the parent and you can see that as a heading. Below that is a menu displaying its children, and further indented are the grandchildren elemets.

Once I click on one of the grandchildren the menu is setting its parent as the parent however I want the menu to stay fixed as the grandparent being the top of the list with the children and then the grandchildren.

Here's an example of what I have

GRANDPARENT
    PARENT
       Child

Once I click on Child it becomes

PARENT
      CHILD

However I wish for the list fo stay as the original full family tree list so to speak.

Does anyone have a snippet of code to work this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use wp_list_categories() defining the parent category/ 'child_of'.

Try the link below:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

Insert the function after de widgets or anything you have in the sidebar.
Remember you can work with the $args array.